# Is there a downside to ksplice?

Tags: linux, kernel, upgrade

`ksplice` is an open source extension of the Linux kernel which allows system administrators to apply security patches to a running kernel without having to reboot the operating system. (From [Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Ksplice).)

Is there a downside to using ksplice? Does it introduce any kind of instability? If not, why is it not included by default in more Linux distributions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically it's very sound, I think that the fact distributions do provide this method of patching yet is:

- It does not integrate with the existing update methods (packaging wise)
- It adds to the burden of the distro to provide another method of upgrading.

Comment: +1 to that.  There would be MANY intricacies to tracking a hot-patched kernel and what hot-patches were applied.  And it doesn't even begin to touch what happens if even a non-hotpatched system would have crashed on a kernel upgrade(panic,fail to boot, etc).  I like having the fall-back option...I don't know if ksplice duplicates the running kernel as a backup or not.

Answer (score 0):

(A disclaimer: I work for Ksplice.)

Re: "Is there a downside to using Ksplice?" you may find the answer to a similar question over at ServerFault to be useful:
https://serverfault.com/questions/78406/is-ksplice-production-ready/

Comment: I don't know why you disclaim anything here, you didn't actually answer the question here... It's generally considered bad behavior for your answer to simply be a link.

Comment: Not sure - but as it is linking to a duplicate, even on ServerFault, I do not think it should have been copied to here.